# Getting Error: EmailException (Java): while using mailR to send mail from Rstudio

Tags: r, smtp

I am trying to send an **email** from **Rstudio** by using `mailR` package but getting Error:

> Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following
> server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465

**version:**

java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)

**Code that I have tried:**

```
mailR::send.mail(from = "xxxx@gmail.com",
          to = c("xxxx@gmail.com"),
          subject = "Test Email from R script",
          body = "Test email from R script by ViSa",
          # html = T,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    port = 465,
                    user.name = "xxxx@gmail.com",
                    passwd = "xxxx",
                    ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Saw some more SO post: [Sending email in R getting Java error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285815/sending-email-in-r-getting-java-error) but it was suggested to use user name which I am already using but still getting this error.

Saw some videos/post about javax beans activation api etc... but there error was different. So do i need to install those.

Or what else should i do ?

**Update:**

I have restarted r session & ran again & now got this error :

> org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the
> following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465  at
> org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)    at
> org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386) Caused by:
> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
> smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;   nested exception is:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol
> (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)     at
> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2055)
> at
> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)     at
> javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)  at
> javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)  at
> javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)    at
> javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
> org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)    ... 6
> more Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate
> protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)    at
> sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.(Unknown Source)  at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.(Unknown Source)    at
> sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)     at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)     at
> com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:543)
> at
> com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:348)
> at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:215)
> at
> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2019)
> ... 13 more Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the
> following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465

Now based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QT51PX4o1qI

I 'av installed `jar` files from: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/javax.activation/1.2.0

and

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0

and placed in `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.0\library\mailR\java`.

But I am still getting this error. Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Have you solved this @ViSa? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @seapen - nope I was still stuck at this.